# .rdlc report bar chart showing only 3 out of 16 items in Category Group

Tags: asp.net, charts, report, rdlc

In an .rdlc report, I show the values of 16 team members in a bar chart. The chart shows all values (Series data) but only 3 Names of team members (Category Groups)[image: bar chart showing what I just described]

The DataSource relies on a stored procedure that goes as follows
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[paTeam1] (@TeamID int) AS SELECT Dim.Dtext, Dim.AusA, Dim.AusB, Tres.Teamfolge, Tres.Fname, Tres.Wert, Tres.Gwert FROM Tres JOIN Dim ON Tres.DimID = Dim.DimID WHERE Tres.TeamID = @TeamID AND Tres.DimID = 1`

The items showing only partially in the Category Groups of the chart depend on "Tres.Fname". All these items exist in the table "Tres".
[image: Part of the table "Tres" showing 2 of the items not shown on the chart]

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the axis -> click Vertical Axis Properties.
In the Axis Options tab (first one from the top) set Interval to 1.

Reference (for horizontal axis, but works for vertical just the same):
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specify-an-axis-interval-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16)